# Python: How to get the string only in the command

Tags: python, pexpect

For some reason, the String of the command gives me the memory reference instead of the simple "pwd" that i am looking for in this example

```
Command is (<tests/olv/olv/install/auto_ovirt_st_setup.InstallTest instance at 0xec118b4c>, 'pwd')
```

The code for the record

```
def run_command_checking_exit_code(*command):
    """ Runs a command"""
    Log.info("Command is " + str(command))

def install_lago(self):
    command = ["ls", "-l"]
    self.run_command_checking_exit_code('pwd')
    """run the conductor profiles required to install OLVM """
    #Log.test_objective('TODO')
    #run_command_checking_exit_code('ls -al')
    """
    yum_list = ["epel-release", "centos-release-qemu-ev", "python-devel", "libvirt", "libvirt-devel", "libguestfs-tools", "libguestfs-devel", "gcc", "libffi-devel", "openssl-devel", "qemu-kvm-ev"]
    for yum in yum_list

    ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST + ' -t OS_OL7U6_X86_64_PVHVM_30GB -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc +'/vm_install_ol7.6', timeout=1000000)
    if ret:
        self.tc_fail('Creation of OLV Engine VM failed')
    ret, msg, tup = self.client.run('/qa/conductor/tests/' + OSSE_OLV_VERSION + '/installer/installerfactory.py -s ' + OSSE_OLV_ENGINE_HOST +' -p ovirt-engine -c 10.1.0.10 -o ' + self.log_jobdir_cc + '/engine_deploy', timeout=1000000)
    if ret:
        self.tc_fail('Install of OLV Engine Host failed')
    self.tc_pass('OLV Engine Host installed')
    """

def main(self):
    self.install_lago()

def __init__(self):
    self.main()
```

Comment: `command` is a tuple here, try `str(command[0])` or `' '.join([str(item) for item in command])`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming run_command_checking_exit_code is part of the same class as the other methods, it should have self in its arg list: `def run_command_checking_exit_code(self, command)`

You do not need the `*` in the method definition, you are simply passing a string to the method and should be able to print that string by just using `command`.

A couple other things:

1) The main() method here is not really needed, you should not have a function whose only line of code is calling another function.

2) If you are wanting to call `run_command_checking_exit_code` with a list instead of a string (like passing it your `command = ['ls', '-l']` list, then you need to research how to print lists in Python. A simple google search will show you several ways to accomplish that.